# crystal reports formula field select row with minimum value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

i have following data :

Name        Amount

 ================

Amit         18000
Ajay         19500
Bharat      16100

how do i print the name with lowest amount in the report footer.

i tried the following formula

```
if {table.amount} = minimum({table.amount}) then
'Lowest Vendor - ' + {table.name}
```

above formula returns a blank value.

I need this in Crystal Reports not in RDBMS.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a local variable and store the value in that and use the variable in report footer.

```
    Shared Stringvar a;
Shared Stringvar b;
    a:=
    if {table.amount} = minimum({table.amount}) then
    'Lowest Vendor - ' + {table.name}
else '0';

if a<>'0'
then b:=a;
```

place this formula beside the amount column.

1. Create another formula and write below formula and place it in footer

   `Shared Stringvar b;
   b`